# How can i stop executing getview() method in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two list view for displaying data from sqlite database.I displayed data without any problem.in second list view i have header with four columns.When i click on first list view , that related data displayed in second list it displayed based on position.By default i displayed first list view of the zero position related data  in second list. the problem is , while scrolling the first list view it automatically calls the zero position values but i need the data of whatever position i clicked on first list view.I displayed data like below.How i can do?
Please can any on help?

first list view:

first........
second........
third........

I displayed data based on selection of first list view.

Second list view:

header

```
            id         Name    Contact

            1          ram     12345
```

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Please post some code to show what you are doing. It is difficult to understand the problem from your description.

Answer (score 1):

easy bruteforce way is to use flag like this..

```
public boolean flag=false; // declare this as class variable outside both listview adapter class
```

then in 1st list view getview() function

```
if(!flag){
       //display 2nd list view contents on 0th position of 1st list
       flag=true;
}
```

in onItemClick() of 1st list view

```
//display 2nd list view contens based on position
```